# Android - AlertDialog on top of any activity without dependency of a particular activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I can create `AlertDialog` on any `Activity` or modify them. I am having a problem on particular scenario. Lets, I have an activity which need read/write permission, camera permission . While user go to activity I ask permission , if granted user can stay there and use that activity otherwise I show a `Toast` saying **Permission Denied!** and exit that activity. If a user tick prevent showing permission, and if he go that activity it shows `Toast` **Permission Denied!** and exit without asking further permission. After ticking this prevent showing permission dialog, the user will never be able to use that `Activity`. So I wanted to show a `AlertDialog`while the activity is exiting. But the problem is as the activity is exiting , so the dialog is. So I want a `AlertDialog`which I will show during `onDestroy()` and still it will show on top of the next  `Activity` on stack .

Comment: I suggest you to use `onActivityResult()` of the activity that starts when the camera activity gets closed. You can set a result from the camera activity, check the resultCode in the activity `onActivityResult()` and then show the `Dialog` which will lay on top of the next `Activity` on stack

Comment: To create a alert dialog, I have to pass the Context reference to that AlertDialog, as Context is superclass of Activity, it will be destroyed when my current activity is finished. So I don't get the last activity reference

Comment: And that's ok, you can use the context (the activity) which is in the `onActivityResult`

Comment: I am gonna close that activity which onActivityResult is called then as the user denied the permission. So I need something which I can refer globally and it will be on top of the previous activity on the stack

Comment: You have to use the activity you just called 'previous' as the activity which will show the dialog!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just use another Dialog themed activity.